# Not able to upgrade python3 to version 3.8 in mac terminal

Tags: python, homebrew

[screenshot of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4LR.png)

Hi,
I am not able to upgrade python3 to version 3.8 using homebrew.
When using the cmd in the terminal, "brew upgrade python3".
its throwing error, python3 not install, but when I checked whether python is installed with cmd in the terminal "python3 --version". its showing Python 3.7.3
Please help, why I am not able to update my python version using homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you already have python 3.8 installed, you can use the **python3.8** command instead of **python3**. But, there are some other steps you can follow:

To quickly check, run:

```
$ brew list | grep python
python
```

Python shows up under the command, it's installed. Now, check the version:

```
$ brew info python
python: stable 3.7.3 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1 (8,437 files, 118MB) *
## further output not included ##
```

The Homebrew maintainers have updated the default Python bottle to point to the latest release. Since the Homebrew maintainers are more dependable at updating the release than most of us, we can use Homebrew's version of Python 3 with the following command:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade python
```

To point our alias (from above) to the copy of Python that Homebrew manages:

```
# If you added the previous alias, use a text editor to update the line to the following
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

To make sure the path above points to where Homebrew installed Python in our environment, we can run brew info python and look for the path information.

Source: [Here](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac)